# Hash map returns a null value

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to download images and save all the downloaded images in a hash map. I tried with the following code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private final Context mContext;
   final String[] mImages;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private static final String TAG = ImageActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] images){
      mContext=context;
      mImages=images;
      mInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mImages[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder.imageView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_View);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        String imageUrl=mImages[position];
        ImageDownloader downloader=new ImageDownloader();
        Bitmap value=downloader.urlMap.get(imageUrl);
        Log.d(TAG, "Print Url:" + value);
        if(value==null){

        downloader.download(imageUrl,viewHolder.imageView);
        }
        else
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(value);
        return convertView;

        }

}
```

But When i debug and check value contains a null value. It should contain a bitmap value.

```
public class ImageDownloader {
    private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024;
    private static final String TAG = ImageActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    final HashMap<String, Bitmap> urlMap=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
     public void download(String url, ImageView imageView) {
         downloadBitmap(url, imageView);

     }


    private void downloadBitmap(final String url,final ImageView imageView) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return downloadUrlToStream(url, imageView);
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                urlMap.put(url, bitmap);
                 Log.d(TAG, "Print value:" + urlMap);
            };
        }.execute();

    }
```

why it's not retrieving the value from hash map?

Comment: You need to pass a `Position` for Retrieving value from `hashMap` like `String url=downloader.urlMap.get(position)`

Comment: But I want too retrieve the bitmap stored in the hash map? If i do this, ill get the key right?

Comment: @SimplePlanm [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does not save elements in any particular order and has no method to retrieve by position. You can get by key, get all keys or all values.

Comment: Bitmap value=downloader.urlMap.get(imageUrl);

This line should do the work.. if you get null is because this url is not in this hashmap.. Can you verify that you inserted the same url in the initialzie?

Comment: I tried to access using  key:                                    Bitmap value=downloader.urlMap.get(imageUrl);

Comment: urlMap.put(url, bitmap);                                                 I gave this key while adding into the hash map. But when i use this key, it gives me error, since m using it in another class.What shall i do for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You create a new downloader for every download:

```
ImageDownloader downloader=new ImageDownloader();
downloader.download(imageUrl,viewHolder.imageView);
```

And your urlMap (that stores the downloaded Bitmap) is not static:

```
final HashMap<String, Bitmap> urlMap=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
```

so you actually loose the downloaded bitmap, because you don't store any reference to ImageDownloader.

However, you should not make it static. You will run out of memory pretty soon, because this way you store all the Bitmaps in the memory.

The recommended solution is to use LRUCache. It's pretty easy to use, the only important thing is to override `sizeOf` correct. Here is the documentation for you:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Actually I'm a beginner, I'm learning the basic things. That is why I want to try using hash map first and then proceed to LRUCache

Comment: And i'm  creating a new downloader for every download, and i made hash map static, but still its not working

Comment: It should work with static. Try to use your debugger to see what items are in your urlMap.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

  private final Context mContext;
  final String[] mImages;
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;
  private static final String TAG = ImageActivity.class.getSimpleName();
   ImageDownloader downloader;

  public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] images){
      mContext=context;
      mImages=images;
      mInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        downloader=new ImageDownloader();
  }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mImages.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mImages[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder.imageView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_View);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
    String imageUrl=mImages[position];

    Bitmap value=downloader.urlMap.get(imageUrl);
    Log.d(TAG, "Print Url:" + value);
    if(value==null){

    downloader.download(imageUrl,viewHolder.imageView);
    }
    else
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(value);
    return convertView;

    }
```

}

Comment: Care to explain the differences?

Comment: when you put ImageDownloader downloader=new ImageDownloader(); in getView funtion it creating every time you scroll the list view and for each item

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try LRU cache the you can use this code

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
List<GalleryDTO> mDatalist;
Activity context;
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
LocationHandler mLocationHandler = null;
public GalleryAdapter(Activity context, List<GalleryDTO> mDatalist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mDatalist = mDatalist;
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            return (int) (getSizeInBytes(bitmap) / 1024);
        }
    };

}

public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}

public long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        return bitmap.getByteCount();
    } else {
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mDatalist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return mDatalist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return mDatalist.get(position).photoId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_gallery, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mPhoto = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
        holder.mProgress = (ProgressBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.pg_list_item);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    GalleryDTO data = (GalleryDTO) getItem(position);
    loadBitmap(data.photoName, holder);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView mPhoto;
    protected ProgressBar mProgress;
}

public void loadBitmap(String respath, ViewHolder holder) {
    final String imageKey = respath;
    final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        holder.mPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        holder.mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        if (cancelPotentialWork(respath, holder.mPhoto, holder.mProgress)) {
            final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(
                    holder.mPhoto, holder.mProgress);
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(
                    context.getResources(), holder.mPlaceHolderBitmap, task);
            holder.mPhoto.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
            task.execute(respath);
        }
    }

}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private final WeakReference<ProgressBar> progressbarReference;
    private String data = "";

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        progressbarReference = new WeakReference<ProgressBar>(progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        data = params[0];
        final Bitmap bitmap = downloadUrlToStream(url);
        addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
        return bitmap;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            final ProgressBar mProgressBar = progressbarReference.get();
            final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(
                    imageView, mProgressBar);
            if (this == bitmapWorkerTask && imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                if (mProgressBar != null)
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}

static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

    public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap,
            BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
        super(res, bitmap);
        bitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(
                bitmapWorkerTask);
    }

    public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
        return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
    }
}

public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(String data, ImageView imageView,
        ProgressBar progressBar) {
    final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(
            imageView, progressBar);

    if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
        final String bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
        if (bitmapData != data) {
            bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView,
        ProgressBar progressBar) {
    if (imageView != null) {
        final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
            return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```